# Why am I getting an asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidPasswordError when my password is what I set when I first downloaded postgresql?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord, discord.py

I've created a database and I'm now trying to create my db pool however I keep getting a password error even though when I first loaded up postgresql and created my account I set my password and it's the same one I'm using in my code. FYI, I'm very new to postgresql and only downloaded it around 3 hours ago. I have also put "password" in as a placeholder for my actual password for obvious reasons.
Code:

```
async def create_db_pool():
    bot.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(user="postgres", password="password", database="testDB")
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\1discord\!!Discord Actual Bots\Waifu Weapons Online\Main Code.py", line 246, in <module>
    bot.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\1discord\!!Discord Actual Bots\Waifu Weapons Online\Main Code.py", line 15, in create_db_pool
    bot.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(user="postgres", password="password", database="testDB")
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\pool.py", line 398, in _async__init__
    await self._initialize()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\pool.py", line 426, in _initialize
    await first_ch.connect()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\pool.py", line 125, in connect
    self._con = await self._pool._get_new_connection()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\pool.py", line 472, in _get_new_connection
    **self._connect_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 1677, in connect
    max_cacheable_statement_size=max_cacheable_statement_size)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 655, in _connect
    connection_class=connection_class)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 631, in _connect_addr
    await asyncio.wait_for(connected, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 358, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidPasswordError: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: What error do you find the PostgreSQL server's log file?

Comment: @jjanes where would i find this?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for anyone who had the same problem as me. I had an old version of postgresql installed and once I uninstalled it and ran the code it then stopped the password error.

Answer (score -2):

The answer suggested is actually not the solution, you have to change deferential of the database.